# How to get error code from eslint when running in pre-commit hook?

Tags: node.js, bash, git, eslint, pre-commit-hook

I have this in my `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

```
npx eslint --max-warnings 1 --exit-on-fatal-error $(git diff --name-only HEAD **/*.ts | xargs)

status=$?

if [ $status -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Good"
  exit 2
fi

if [ $status -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "Bad"
  exit 2
fi

if [ $status -eq 2 ]
then
  echo "Worse"
  exit 2
fi
```

It always prints "Good", even if I have a valid ESLint error. I can tell the ESLint errors out when I run it directly on the CLI, it outputs stuff like:

```
$ npx eslint --max-warnings 0 --exit-on-fatal-error make/link/fold/index.ts

./make/link/fold/index.ts
  325:14  error  Expected a default case  default-case

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

How do I capture the error from eslint and prevent the commit from happening if there is an error?

I have never really done this before, always used it in other peoples projects, trying to configure now. Tried for a while, no luck.

Comment: `npx eslint --max-warnings 1` vs `npx eslint --max-warnings 0` ?

Comment: No that doesn't help. It still successfully runs even with eslint errors.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
while read -r ts; do
  npx eslint --max-warnings 1 --exit-on-fatal-error "$ts"
  status=$?

  case $status in
    0)
      echo "Good"
      exit 0
    ;;
    1)
      echo "Bad"
      exit 1
    ;;
    1)
      echo "Worse"
      exit 2
    ;;
    *)
      echo "WTF ?!"
      exit 3
    ;;
  esac
done < <(git diff --name-only HEAD **/*.ts)
```

The `case` statement lets you match a word against several patterns and execute commands based on which one matches. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Choices and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case and 'case word in' in `man bash`.

Comment: Updated the first command with `git`, I suspect the subshell to hide what we need